# django api using generic views for deleting multiple objects

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to use django generic view. and i want to be able to delete multiple objects at the same time using the same view.for example delete all the 'femail' Employees in my model.
i used the following code:

```
from ..models import Employee
from . import serializer
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404

class EmployeeDeleteandUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.filter(gender__startswith='femail')
    serializer_class = serializer.PostSerializer

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        myobj = get_object_or_404(Employee, gender=kwargs['gender'])
        myobj.delete()
        return Response("Femails deleted", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

and heres my url code:

```
path('mydel/<str:gender>/', view.EmployeeDeleteandUpdate.as_view()),
```

and also my model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    national_code = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    personal_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    married = models.BooleanField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    wage = models.IntegerField()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.first_name
```

but when i use delete method with following url in my django rest framework:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mydel/femail/
```

i get this error:

> client.models.Employee.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more
> than one Employee -- it returned 2!

can somebody help me with this problem please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get_object_or_404 method only gets 1 object from the table so it is compulsory the record will be unique in the table. Otherwise, it gives an error.

Please try this code:

```
  def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employees = Employee.objects.filter(gender=kwargs['gender'])
        if employees.count() > 0:
           employees.delete()
           return Response("Femails deleted", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response("Unable to find the femails.", status=status.HTTP_404_OK)
```

In this code snippet, I am filtering the result based on kwargs['gender'] and then count its objects if greater than one then delete it using the loop.